# wcf and android - how to avoid Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: android, json, wcf, web-services

Ive been sending data to a wcf webservice thats choking on complex json. When I run the debugger I can see the wcf totally ignores the incomming values and when I try to set the parameter I get Unrecognized escape sequence. How can I force the wcf to just accept the data and stop complaining like a broken old lady.

Heres my json going in that gets turned into null

```
{"dtTourReports":["{\"ReportedBy\":\"0101\",\"TourReportData\":[{\"ReportDataType\":\"text\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":11,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Person in Charge-Persona ancargada\",\"ReportData\":\"Jamie Andresakis\"},{\"ReportDataType\":\"bool\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":12,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Dry-Clean\",\"ReportData\":\"true\"},{\"ReportDataType\":\"bool\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":13,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Wet-Spill\",\"ReportData\":\"true\"},{\"ReportDataType\":\"bool\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":14,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Food Spill\",\"ReportData\":\"true\"},{\"ReportDataType\":\"text\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":15,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Other\",\"ReportData\":\"Test\"},{\"ReportDataType\":\"text\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":16,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Comments\",\"ReportData\":\"Test \"},{\"ReportDataType\":\"time\",\"ReportDataTypeID\":17,\"ReportDataTypeTitle\":\"Time of Inspection\",\"ReportData\":\"11-25-2013 07:29:18 PM\"}],\"localID\":1,\"TourInstanceID\":1,\"TourDetailID\":43,\"TourReportTypeID\":2,\"TourReportType\":\"Area Report\",\"TourReportComments\":\"Person in Charge-Persona ancargada: User 1<br \\\/> <br \\\/>Other: Test<br \\\/> <br \\\/>Comments: Test <br \\\/> <br \\\/>\",\"DateCreated\":\"11-25-2013 07:29:35 PM\"}"]}
```

Comment: Wait, is that string there (the first array element of `dtTourReports`) JSON itself?  Was that what you intended?

Comment: Its a jsonarray of jsonobjects sent from an android device. There can be many other dtXXXX's but this is the one it had problems with. I actually fixed this by using a JSONStringer in android. For what ever reason sending the json formatted with that instead of normal JSONObjects worked better. It probably had something to do with extra escapes using JSONObject's added to the request string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up fixing the problem. I guess when using JSONObject's and putting them into a jsonarray you end up with extra escapes that wcf complains about.

```
if(cr.moveToFirst()){

        reports = new JSONArray();

        do{

            try{

                SessionData session = new SessionData(getApplicationContext());

                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._ReportData)));

                 JSONStringer jo = new JSONStringer().object().
                         key("ReportedBy").value(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._CreatedBy)) != 0
                         ? cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._CreatedBy)) : session.UserID_get()).
                         key("TourReportData").value(ja).
                         key("localID").value(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._LocalID))).
                         key("TourInstanceID").value(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._TourInstanceID))).
                         key("TourDetailID").value(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._TourDetailID))).
                         key("TourReportTypeID").value(cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(gh.GuardTourReports_ReportTypeID))).
                         key("TourReportType").value(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(gh.GuardTourReports_ReportType))).
                         key("TourReportComments").value(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._TourReportComments))).
                             key("DateCreated").value(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(gh._DateCreated)))
                .endObject();

                reports.put(jo);
            }
            catch(JSONException jse){
                jse.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }while(cr.moveToNext());
```